# ActionController::ParameterMissing in create using form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My form_tag looks like this:

```
 <%= form_tag(user_jobs_path(title: job.title, company: job.company, url: job.url, description: job.description), method: "post") do %>
    <button>Add to My Jobs</button>
 <% end %>
```

...and this is going to the standard restful create action and strong params:

```
 def create
    @user_job = UserJob.new(user_job_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_job.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user_job, notice: 'User job was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user_job }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user_job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

    def user_job_params
      params.require(:user_job).permit(:tite, :company, :url, :description, :user_id, :notes, :applied, :applied_on)
    end
```

I feel like a need to reformat my params in the form_tag so they are nested in something called `user_job` but not sure what the looks like. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this with my form_tag:

```
        <%= form_tag(user_jobs_path(user_job: {title: job.title, company: job.company, 
          url: job.url, description: job.description}), method: "post") do %>
         <button>Add to My Jobs</button>
      <% end %>
```

...using the `user_job:` symbol and including the model attributes in curly braces.